# What is the odds of rolling specific numbers on 4 d20s?

Tags: dice, statistics

If I roll 1d20, then 1d20, then 1d20, then 1d20 (effectively 4d20), what are the odds that I'll roll specific numbers? For example, all 20's, or a combination of numbers such as (1, 16, 16, 1)?

Comment: Does order matter for this? In other words would you consider the following rolls to be different: [1, 2, 3, 4] vs [4, 3, 2, 1]?

Comment: I'm curious what the odds would be for each result, with order mattering and without order mattering.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @Crater Then it depends. 20 20 20 20 only has one possible order; 1 16 16 1 has more than one possible order.

Comment: I am voting to close this as off-topic because I feel it is more suited for [Statistics Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or perhaps [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com). Questions exclusively about dice [are typically considered off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9082).

Comment: @D M What would the probability be for 1, 16, 16, 1 be for example?

Comment: @Crater Please don't try to get around question closure by prompting for answering the the comments. You can take the question to [statistics.se], but you might want to look around to see if it is already asked there and if you do ask it anew, you might be well served to include what you have tried yourself to figure it out and why you haven't been able.